# Moving data from one dataframe to another in pandas with one column that is identical

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

So I am still going through pandas and having a little trouble with doing this

Dataset 1

```
Sample Age   Tumor     Location
   3   31    Benign      Lung
   8   45   Malignant    Heart
   9   44   Malignant    Heart
```

Dataset 2

```
Sample Age   Tumor     Location
   3   None  None        None 
   8   None  None        None 
   9   None  None        None
```

What I want I am trying to do is move the data from dataset 1 to dataset 2 based on the sample column so it is mapped correctly

Like so

Dataset 2

```
Sample Age   Tumor     Location
   3   31    Benign      Lung
   8   45   Malignant    Heart
   9   44   Malignant    Heart
```

I can't seem to find an example yet that does this. Other than merging the two into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Using `update` and assuming the `'Sample'` is unique key for map

```
df2=df2.set_index('Sample')
df2.update(df1.set_index('Sample'))
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2
Out[1046]: 
   Sample Age      Tumor Location
0       3  31     Benign     Lung
1       8  45  Malignant    Heart
2       9  44  Malignant    Heart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)) to set columns based on conditions placed on the rows. An example below:

```
#Setup
import pandas as pd

dataset_1 = {
        'Sample': [3, 8, 9], 
        'Age': [31, 45, 44], 
        'Tumor': ['Benign', 'Malignant', 'Malignant'],
        'Location': ['Lung', 'Heart', 'Heart']
        }
dataset_2 = {
        'Sample': [3, 8, 9], 
        'Age': [None, None, None], 
        'Tumor': [None, None, None],
        'Location': [None, None, None]
        }

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dataset_2)
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
```

Which outputs:

```
   Age Location  Sample      Tumor
0   31     Lung       3     Benign
1   45    Heart       8  Malignant
2   44    Heart       9  Malignant
    Age Location  Sample Tumor
0  None     None       3  None
1  None     None       8  None
2  None     None       9  None
```

This is how to use `loc` to set columns equal where the rows of some column are equal to the rows of another. 
In this case, the columns being compared are the `Sample` columns of the two dataframes:

```
df_2.loc[df_2.Sample == df_1.Sample, :] = df_1

print(df_1)
print(df_2)
```

Which gives us:

```
   Age Location  Sample      Tumor
0   31     Lung       3     Benign
1   45    Heart       8  Malignant
2   44    Heart       9  Malignant
   Age Location  Sample      Tumor
0   31     Lung       3     Benign
1   45    Heart       8  Malignant
2   44    Heart       9  Malignant
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Good luck!